# SqlCommand returns all records even though parameters are specified

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got a simple ASP.NET web form with 5 text boxes and a submit button to filter a result set returned from a database.

Regardless of what is entered, the `DataAdapter` is filled with the complete contents of the table without any of the parameters included.

What's the problem with my code?

```
 private void BindGridView()
 {
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer2005DBConnectionString"].ToString()))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

         cmd.CommandText = "select Cust_SID, First_name, Last_name, Address1, Phone1, Email_addr from Customer where 1=1";

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtAddress.Text + "%";
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text + "%");
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "%" + txtLastName.Text + "%");
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", "%" + txtEmail.Text + "%");
         }

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhone.Text))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", "%" + txtPhone.Text + "%");
         }

         conn.Open();

         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataSet dsCustomer = new DataSet();

         da.Fill(dsCustomer, "Customer");

         DataView dvCustomer = dsCustomer.Tables["Customer"].DefaultView;
         dvCustomer.Sort = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();

         gvCustomer.DataSource = dvCustomer;
         gvCustomer.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have where 1=1 in your sql statement?

Comment: You forgot to apply conditions against your parameter. You never build the condition part of your query.

Comment: Slight detour. Since you are using pass through sql you should also take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's a great article and I will heed the advice. Thanks others for the downvotes, a few more and I won't be able to post again. I spent a lot of time on this today, didn't just throw up a question frivolously. I don't understand why the harshness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually include the parameters in your SQL:

```
cmd.CommandText = 
    "select Cust_SID, First_name, Last_name, Address1, Phone1, Email_addr " +
    "from Customer where 0=1";

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text))
{
    cmd.CommandText += " or Address1 like @Address1";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                  .Value = "%" + txtAddress.Text + "%";
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text))
{
    cmd.CommandText += " or First_name like @FirstName";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text + "%");
}

// and so on for each parameter
```

Comment: Is this the part I was missing? If I make the initial CommandText as you show, what happens if only one of the parameters is used? Does the SqlCommand know to truncate it? I guess this is where I'm having the issue.

Comment: Ah, no. Edit incoming.

Comment: See edit. You have to build the SQL to match the parameters yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Blorgbeard ! This is exactly what I needed to know, I was totally missing this.

Comment: This will still return all rows since `1=1` is always true, and you are using `OR` statements. The simplest solution (though not the most elegant one) is to change the first clause to `WHERE 0=1`

Comment: @TimCooke hah, oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL-string is sometimes a bit confusing.

The first part `SELECT` is executed at the end of the request to the database.

The first thing that the database adapter does is enter the table (`FROM` tableName).

Second thing is the comparison of the `WHERE` statements.
Here you can choose which rows the database need to return.
E.g. WHERE column1="someValue".
You'll get al the rows where column1 is "someValue".

Third are the `group by` and the `order by` statements.

And finnaly, from the internal list of rows that the database holds for that request (after the WHERE), you can `SELECT` which columns you want.
If you want all the colums you simply put * , otherwise you give onze of more column names of even "MAX(columName)" which give you the highest number in that column (only for numeric columns).

You can code your SQL strings in two ways:

`First` way is hardcoding the WHERE statements. This is acceptable if the parameter is not a complex type like `DateTime`:

```
"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column1=" + variable;
```

`Second` way is using parameters. This way is better because the SqlCommand object will convert your parameters to the right DbType:

```
"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column1=@paramerter1";
var t = com.CreateParameter();
t.ParameterName = "@parameter1";
t.Value = variable;
com.Parameters.Add(t);
```

A good program to test your sql-strings is "SqlTryOut".
A Google search will do.